# Dresden Files Rote Spell Rolls

Tags: dresden-files

Lets say I have a rote spell set up with 4 shifts for a straight attack.  Because it's a rote spell I don't have to make a 4 on my discipline roll, but I still role the discipline for the attack.

So, does that mean that if I role a discipline of 2 that I do 6 stress (excluding any defense)?

Or am I wrong and I just do the 4 stress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's still an attack, so an opposed roll is still required. Since it's an attack evocation, your "attack roll" uses Discipline. The only difference is that you're not *also* using this same roll to control the energy of the evocation: you automatically get a roll of 0 to control it.

So **yes**, you still roll Discipline in an opposed roll against the target's defense, and *if* you win the contest, you get to add the rote's weapon rating (4) to the shifts you got in the opposed roll to determine the total stress inflicted.